# Drawing balls with different subsets, without replacement, order matters

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of $n$ elements, consisting of $s$ subsets $ie. n = 25$ elements, $s = 6$ subsets with $3, 2, 5, 2, 9, 4 $ elements . The balls within the subsets are indistinguishable. $ K $ Balls are drawn without replacement. The order matters. 
I would like to know the number of possible combinations:

Initially, I would calculate 6 possibilities for the first draw, 6 for the second and so on, giving me $s^k (6^4)$. However, as I draw without replacement, some combinations are not possible (the subsets are too small). How do I exclude the number of non-possible combinations efficiently?

Comment: Check whether this a correct interpretation of your question: there are $25$ balls. $3$ of them have color red, $2$ have color blue,...,etc. This for $6$ distinct colors. Then $k$ balls are drawn without replacement. How many combinations of color are possible if the order of the colors matters?

Comment: Yes, this interpretation is correct!